# Serverside pre-rendering in Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core cause timeout when HTTP requests are used

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

Using [this article and templates](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/), I build an Angular 2 application powered by ASP.NET Core. Serverside pre-rendering works, until HTTP requests are made to fetch some data.

Simple example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { SchoolSubject, TimetableDay, TimetableSubject } from '../components/timetable/timetable-models';

@Injectable()
export class TimetableService {
    private baseUrl: string = '/ClassBook/Timetable/';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAllSubjects(): Observable<TimetableSubject[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'GetAllSubjects')
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        console.log('Body: ' + JSON.stringify(body));
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error("ERROR: "+errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

I call the `getAllSubjects` method from the timetable component. When I open this in the browser like opening the app in the home-component, then klick on the link to the timetable-component so that it's rendered in the browser without serverside prerendering, it works fine.

But when I open the URL of the timetable component directly so that it's prerendered by the server, I get an timeout:

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering
>   timed out after 30000ms because the boot function in
>   'Areas/ClassBook/ClientApp/dist/main-server' returned a promise that
>   did not resolve or reject. Make sure that your boot function always
>   resolves or rejects its promise. You can change the timeout value
>   using the 'asp-prerender-timeout' tag helper.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.d__7`1.MoveNext()

It only happens when HTTP requests are made. Using components without HTTP requests like /home or /counter from the example template, are working correctly. I tried to enable [debugging of serverside JS](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#debugging-your-javascripttypescript-code-when-it-runs-on-the-server), but seems not to work, too. The result is an empty debug console or an exception, that the connection has been lost after capturing the request.

The dev machine is Windows 10 Pro, there both working correctly. But the app should be running inside a docker-container using the official images from Microsoft, there the timeout occur.

Comment: The link at the top of this question points to http://localhost:5000/ClassBook/timetable

Comment: @R.Richards Sorry, I fixed the link.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?